# Few questions about sum of sum of digits of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume we have four numbers: $A, B, C, S$.
$A$ is a natural number.
Sum of digits of $A = B$.
Sum of digits of $B = C$.
And $S = A + B + C$.
(e.g. if $A = 3469$, then $B = 22$, $C = 4$ and $S = 3469 + 22 + 4 = 3495$)
My questions are:

1. How to prove that $S$ is always divisible by $3$?
2. How many three-digit $A$ numbers are there for which $C = 3$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know that $A\equiv B\pmod 9$?

Comment: As for (2), the sum of the digits of a number from $001$ to $999$ is somewhere between $1$ and $27$.  The sum of the sum of the digits of a number from $001$ to $999$ is going to be the sum of the digits of a number from $1$ to $27$ and is going to be somewhere from $1$ to $10$.  You should be able to reason then that those three digit numbers for whom the sum of the digits of the sum of the digits being $3$ will be precisely those numbers who are $3$ more than a multiple of $9$, one ninth of the three digit numbers being 3 more than a multiple of nine.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen as for 1 I think that it can be proved if we prove that $A\mod3 = B\mod3 = C\mod3$. But I'm not sure about this statement. With the second problem I have came up with an answer 100. That is because if we say that $C$ is divisible by $3$, then $B$ is divisible by 3 too, and that means that $A$ should be divisible by 9. Then we take the least three-digit number that is divisible by 9, which is 102, and count every other number by repeatedly adding 9, until we reach 1000.

Comment: Pay more attention to @HagenvonEitzen ’s question-comment. Think a bit more globally, perhaps. It might also help to reset your outlook to the mathematical one of looking at congruence classes modulo $9$, rather than the computer-science outlook of “mod” as an operator.

Comment: @Lubin I didn't know about such a concept. I've read now some information about congruence classes on internet, but I think I still do not understand their meaning properly. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but does this mean, because of $A \equiv B(\mod9)$ and $B\equiv C(\mod9)$, I can say that $A\equiv C(\mod9)$? If so, then I think I can represent their sum as $S = \overbrace{С+9a}^{A} + \overbrace{C + 9b}^{B} + C = 3C + 9(ab)$, which is surely divisible by $3$. Anyway, thanks for advice!

Comment: @JMoravitz now I understand. We can get $C = 3$ if $B$ is either $30, 21, 12$ or $3$, and all of them can be represented as $9k + 3$ as you've said, but I didn't noticed that. Also $30$ is not valid as it's too big to be $B$, but that does not makes sense for calculating real answer. Then we find all $k \in \mathbb {Z}$ such that $99 < 9k + 3 < 1000 \Rightarrow 10.(6) < k < 110.(7)$ and that leads us to the answer $=100$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, your computation, involving adding something to itself three times, is the right way to see things. I must say that this is the clearest evidence I’ve seen yet of the superiority of using “$\pmod n$” to the computer-science way of looking at these matters.

Answer (score -1):

1:

Let's start with a basic proof that the sum of the digits of a number mod 3 is the same as the number itself mod 3.

First step: We start with the fact that 10 ≡ 1 (mod 3) and 1 ≡ 10 (mod 3)

Next step: We write *a* as $10^i*n_1 + 10^{i-1}*n_2 + ... + 10^{j}*n_{i-j+1}$ (Aka the base 10 representation)

Final step: By the 1st and 2nd steps, we thus can conclude that a ≡ $n_1 + n_2 + ... + n_{i-j+1}$

We can then conclude that the sum of the digits of a number mod 3 is the same as the number itself mod 3. Because $k+k+k = 3k ≡ 0\ (mod\ 3)$, *a* + *b* + *c* is always divisible by 3.

---

2:

I'll break up the second question into cases

Case 1:

*b* = 3

The 3 digit numbers are 102, 111, 120, 201, 210, 300, for a total of 6.

Case 2:

*b* = 12

This will be broken into subcases

Subcase 1:

Use the numbers 9, 3, 0. Total: 3! - 2 = 4

Subcase 2:

Use the numbers 9, 2, 1. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 3:

Use the numbers 8, 2, 2. Total: 3

Subcase 4:

Use the numbers 8, 3, 1. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 5:

Use the numbers 8, 4, 0. Total: 3! - 2 = 4

Subcase 6:

Use the numbers 7, 5, 0. Total: 3! - 2 = 6

Subcase 7:

Use the numbers 7, 4, 1. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 8:

Use the numbers 7, 3, 2. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 9:

Use the numbers 6, 6, 0. Total: 606 & 660, 2

Subcase 10:

Use the numbers 6, 5, 1. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 11:

Use the numbers 6, 4, 2. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 12:

Use the numbers 6, 3, 3. Total: 3

Subcase 13:

Use the numbers 5, 5, 2. Total: 3

Subcase 14:

Use the numbers 5, 4, 3. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 15:

Use the numbers 4, 4, 4. Total: 1

Summing the numbers gives a total of 68 cases

Case 3:

*b* = 21

Again, I will write a few subcases

Subcase 1:

Use the numbers 9, 9, 3. Total: 3

Subcase 2:

Use the numbers 9, 8, 4. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 3:

Use the numbers 9, 7, 5. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 4:

Use the numbers 9, 6, 6. Total: 3

Subcase 5:

Use the numbers 8, 8, 5. Total: 3

Subcase 6:

Use the numbers 8, 7, 6. Total: 3! = 6

Subcase 7:

Use the numbers 7, 7, 7. Total: 1

Totaling gives us 28 cases

Now, for the grand finale, 6 + 68 + 28 gives us a grand total of 100 different values of *a* when *c* is 3

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I think in second task you have miscalculated somewhere. I have bruteforced this problem, and my program shows that the answer is 100.

Comment: Oh... I see where I went wrong 

Comment: Your analysis of question 2 is horribly tedious.  You should avoid casework and brute force whenever possible.  Follow the outline of my solution I gave in the comments above to *very quickly* say that as there are $900$ three digit numbers and $\frac{1}{9}$ of them satisfy the condition there are $900/9 = 100$ such numbers... no casework needed.

Comment: It could have been a one or two sentence solution... instead you gave a multi-page solution that grates the eyes with one line blurring into the next, making it difficult to verify at a glance if every case was correctly accounted for, if some were repeated, or some were missed, if the arithmetic was done correctly, etc...